# how to create video thumpnail image using paperclip?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

Im using paperclip for video uploading in my rails application.But i dont know how to get thumbnail image. Can anyone help me to achieve and give reference links as well..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
    gem 'paperclip-av-transcoder'
```

for generating thumbnails
[link](https://github.com/ruby-av/paperclip-av-transcoder)